# Converting G.729 audio to PCM using python

Tags: python, voip, codec, telephony

I am dealing with wav files encoded in G.279 and need to convert them to PCM LE16 through python code which runs on an ubuntu server. So far I have tried ffmpeg and scikit.audiolabs and both of them failed to read the audio file. Whats the best way to convert the G.279 to PCM format in python?